# Page Jump and Onclick Return

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to insert a link that will page jump and return a tab

but I can only get one or the other to work what code will allow both?

```
 <a href="#returns" onclick="return show('tab3')">Click Here To View Warranty Details</A>
```

For example I am trying to create a link that says under the "comes with a 1 year audio savings warranty" to say *Click here to View Warranty Details* It will then scroll down to the information and policies section and open the return policy tab.

http://www.ebay.com/itm/Kenwood-KDC-BT752HD-1-Din-In-Dash-CD-MP3-USB-HD-Receiver-Bluetooth-8GB-USB-Drive-/300777979602?pt=Car_Audio_In_Dash_Receivers&vxp=mtr&hash=item4607c3bed2

Thanks

also ebay does not support Iframe code so is there any other code that will work?

Comment: What does show tab do? I am guessing that the function returns false which cancels the click action so it will not navigate there.

Comment: You want to open the same link twice? Yummy Spam. I think that would confuse your users.

Comment: Well im not quite sure what code to use to perform this task, Im not trying to open two links i'm not too familiar with the code so Im just trial and erroring. And no this isnt spam I would just like to answer this it is ebay policy that this tag be added to the ebay items we have listed.